# Can Magnific Popup contain a slider?

Tags: jquery, magnific-popup, swiper.js

I'm creating a website with a gallery of multiple images. These images essentially act a covers--when clicked on I'd like to use Magnific Popup to open a lightbox containing a slideshow of images within that item only (not going from gallery item 1, to gallery item 2, etc...) I've already got the slideshow set up using the Swiper plug-in and would like to open this in the popup window. I know you can open html content in the popup, but what about a div which contains an entire slideshow? It seems logical, but I can't get it to work.

Comment: Check http://dimsemenov.com/plugins/royal-slider/slider-in-lightbox/

Answer (score 0):

I just had to do this with Flexslider inside of a Magnific Popup. To get it to work, I needed to initialize Flexslider in the Magnific callback.

```
$('.ajaxpop').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    callbacks: {
        parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
            mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#slider-container');
        },
        ajaxContentAdded: function() {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider({
                  animation: "slide"
             }); 

         }

    }
});
```

It would be a similar process for whatever slider you're using.

Answer (score 0):

```
  $('.open-popup-link').magnificPopup({
    type: 'ajax',
    callbacks: {
     parseAjax: function(mfpResponse) {
     mfpResponse.data = $(mfpResponse.data).find('#sliderContainer');
    },
    ajaxContentAdded: function() {
       $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({

      navigation : true,
      nav : true, // Show next and prev buttons
      slideSpeed : 600,
      paginationSpeed : 700,
      singleItem:true,


      // "singleItem:true" is a shortcut for:
       items : 1, 
      // itemsDesktop : false,
      // itemsDesktopSmall : false,
      // itemsTablet: false,
      // itemsMobile : false

  });

     }

}

});
```

Comment: This snippet for Owl Carousel in maginfic Pop up inspired by slider in  light box.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind changing the library, I suggest Slick-lightbox for this.

https://github.com/mreq/slick-lightbox/

It works together with Slick:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/